# Measure of expected inflation

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy, inflation

How is expected inflation measured for policy purposes? Is it based on some economic model or some survey?

Comment: To get an accurate answer you probably have to specify which country you are curious about.

Answer (score 3):

There are three big sources for data on inflation expectations in the US:

1. Market implied expectations from the TIPS spread. TIPS securities provide inflation protection but are otherwise roughly comparable to normal treasuries, so the difference in yields between these two is a measure of expected inflation.
2. Consumer expectations from the University of Michigan Survey of Consumers, which you can find [here](https://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/MICH).
3. Surveys of professional forecasters, such as [this survey](https://www.phil.frb.org/research-and-data/real-time-center/survey-of-professional-forecasters).

Which of these measures is most useful is not clear, and I've seen all three used at different times and in different places. [This speech by Janet Yellen](http://www.federalreserve.gov/newsevents/speech/yellen20150924a.htm#f28) has some discussion of the different measures, as does [this paper by Carola Binder](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176515003286).